# CDC difference between capture instance table and SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis, cdc

I recently found out CDC feature and it is very cool. I'd like to implement it at my work and one thing I am still not clear about is the purpose of SSIS package. Please bear with me since it's very new to me.

When I enabled database and table I want to track of, I can get all changes from instance table (_CT) and stored procs/functions. I know it only keeps data for three days by default, but I can still make this retention value larger. And making archive table with this _CT table does make more sense to me at this point.

But all references about CDC packages are about full/incremental load for source tables. My source table is huge since it is transaction table, don't want to make another staging table with full load for this process. Is it really necessary?  Basically my question is the difference and if I need this CDC full/incremental SSIS pkg for source table or I can just keep archiving _CT table.

Thanks

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you just want to extract Delta's i.e. the changes?

Comment: Thank you Michael, I want to store Deleted transactions and old value of updated ones. And of course, archive all changes in the separate table.